# Gerar combinações matemáticas com array em PHP

Tags: php, combinações

GERAR todas combinações possíveis de 15 elementos a partir de um array com 17 ítens. Essa é uma situação hipotética. Deve servir para qualquer combinação n por p.

No total de 136 combinações.
Usando a fórmula matemática para Combinações:

```
Cn,p
C17,15 = 17!/(15!*2!)
```

???? como fazer? sugestões, exemplos?

```
//Código

//array com 17 dezenas

dezenas = ["2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12", "15", "16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25"];

//Gerar todas combinações possíveis de array com 15 dezenas

 array1 = ["2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12", "15", "16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23"];

 array2 = ["2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12", "15", "16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "24"];

//etc... etc...
```

Comment: Editei a resposta com a complementação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As combinações de 17 elementos de 15 em 15 podem ser definidas de forma recursiva usando a seguinte função:

```
$dezenas = array("2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9", "10", "12", "15", "16", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25");

function combinacoesDe($k, $xs){
     if ($k === 0)
         return array(array());
     if (count($xs) === 0)
         return array();
     $x = $xs[0];
     $xs1 = array_slice($xs,1,count($xs)-1);
     $res1 = combinacoesDe($k-1,$xs1);
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($res1); $i++) {
         array_splice($res1[$i], 0, 0, $x);
     }
     $res2 = combinacoesDe($k,$xs1);
     return array_merge($res1, $res2);
}


print_r(combinacoesDe(15,$dezenas));
```

[**Resultado - ideone**](https://ideone.com/nUFfOC)

> A partir do PHP 5.4 você também pode utilizar a sintaxe contraída de array, que troca array() por [].

Link para gerar combinação on-line
[Online calculator: Combinatorics. Generator of combinations](https://planetcalc.com/3757/)

---

---

O numero de combinações é dado pela formula

```
                 n!
      Cn,p = ___________     
             p! (n – p)!
```

- n é a quantidade de elementos de um conjunto
- p é um número natural menor ou igual a n, que representa a quantidade de elementos que irão formar os agrupamentos.

Fazendo a conta sem maquina de calcular teremos :)

```
                 17!
     C17,15 = ____________     
             15! (17 – 15)!


               (1*2*3*.......*15)*16*17     16*17
     C17,15 =  _________________________ = ______ = 8*17= 8*(10+7)=80+56=136
               (1*2*3*.......*15)*1*2        1*2
```

Comment: Obrigado @Leo Caracciolo ! Resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Amigo, só para complementar...
Tenho um banco de dados com todos resultados da Lotofácil. Como deve saber em cada sorteio são sorteadas 15 dezenas.
Como faria para em cada passagem do FOR acima comparar o array de 15 dezenas gerado com todos registro do banco de dados? A ideia é evitar usar um jogo já sorteado. A parte do select no BD sei fazer.
Eu usava uma planilha com todos resultados para fazer essa comparação. Agora estou criando uma aplicação em PHP para automatizar essa tarefa.

Comment: Sua dica me ajudou porque jogo volantes com 17 dezenas. Um jogo de 17 dezenas equivale a combinação de 136 jogos de 15 dezenas. A comparação com o BD tem que ser 15 a 15.

Comment: @Ronda, entendi. editei a resposta com a complementação.

Comment: Desculpe reviver essa postagem, é que preciso de uma coisa relacionada a isso. @Leo Caracciolo você sabe como posso gerar essas combinações com garantia de acertos? Como essa função é para criar combinações para jogos de loteria, existe a possibilidade de garantir premiação, caso dentro das dezenas escolhidas para as combinação, tenha alguns números sorteados. Por exemplo: 17 dezenas escolhida para combinação, garantindo 11 pontos em pelo menos 1 cartela.

Comment: @BrunoOliveira, pelo que vi a probabilidade de acertar 11 pontos com 17 dezenas apostadas é de 1 em 3, portanto não há garantia de acertar pelo menos uma cartela. https://www.sorteonline.com.br/lotofacil/probabilidades

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo então... Na verdade não é uma aposta com 17 dezenas... São 17 dezenas escolhidas para gerar cartões de apostas com 15 dezenas. A garantia de 11 acertos é se as 15 dezenas sorteadas, estiverem dentro das 17 dezenas utilizadas para gerar esses cartões. O código que você postou, gera 136 cartões de 15 dezenas. No caso de uma função com essa garantia de 11 acertos, geraria apenas 21 cartões. Exemplo: Nesse mesmo site que enviou o link, na parte de apostas da lotofacil, se você selecionar 17 dezenas, ele vai te oferecer um fechamento com 17 dezenas garantindo 14 acertos.